# URL modification to return specific paragraph

Tags: url

Given the numerous paragraphs in:

http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0718/Sections/0718.111.html

How can the hyperlink be augmented to return the same webpage, but with the desired paragraph at the top of the web browser?

Assume that there is a unique "handle" in the text content that would enable a search to return the paragraph.  In the example below: "all reasonable times" returns the target paragraph.

Example:

[image]

UPDATE:

[https://www.septicsolutions.com/customer-service/knowledge-base/selecting-the-correct-control-panel#:~:text=Simplex%20Control%20Panels%20are%20used,a%20lift%20or%20pump%20station](https://www.septicsolutions.com/customer-service/knowledge-base/selecting-the-correct-control-panel#:%7E:text=Simplex%20Control%20Panels%20are%20used,a%20lift%20or%20pump%20station).

Comment: It is not possible in your example. Generally a link can be generated when there is `<a href="#link">` tag in HTML code.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks for responding.  I do not understand your comment: can you provide a link to clarify?

Comment: This explains how @Biswapriyo's suggestion works: http://freepages.rootsweb.com/~pasher/computers/anchors.htm  But since you're not dealing with static html but rather HTML that's generated on the fly, you'd have to be able to modify how the HTML's generated, so as to include name anchors.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome, Edge and related browser, install [Link to Fragment](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-to-text-fragment/pbcodcjpfjdpcineamnnmbkkmkdpajjg?hl=en) extension:

> This extension allows for easily creating a special link to the currently selected text on a page via the context menu. When opening such a special link, a compatible browser will scroll the selected text into view and highlight it.

Clicking this [link](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0718/Sections/0718.111.html#statutes:%7E:text=The%20official%20records%20of%20the%20association%20are,knowingly%20denied%20access%20to%20the%20records.) should lead you to the paragraph shown on the OP's image.

**Caveats:** For unknown reasons, the link is opening on the correct paragraph only when I am editing mode in Superuser. It usually works correctly.

[image]

Comment: Very nice animated gif!     Is said link suppose to work in browsers not outfitted with extensions?  I tested the link with a Safari browser and was not successful.

Comment: @gatorback Just a comment, but I believe the ability to link to text fragments is currently limited to Chromium clones (Chrome, Edge, Opera), since it isn't actually a standard (it's an option Google simply chose to add to Chrome, etc). To the best of my knowledge, Firefox hasn't implemented it (yet) and I believe Safari doesn't have this ability at this time either.